# new RealmSwift 0.95.0 brings three compiler warnings

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Today, I updated to the brandnew RealmSwift 0.95.0 and observed three compiler warnings. (using XCode-6.4 / iOS-8.4.1 / OSX-10.10.5 / Swift-1.2 / install with CocoaPods)

Can anybody tell me on how to get rid of the three warnings ?
Thanks!

The warnings are as follows... (see screenshots) :

Warning1: in File RealmSwift/Migration.swift
(...defaultPath was depreciated in version 1: Use Configuration.defaultConfiguration...)
[image]

Warning2: in File RealmSwift/Realm.swift
(...defaultPath was depreciated in version 1: Use Configuration.defaultConfiguration...)
[image]

Warning3: in File RealmSwift/RealmConfiguration.swift
(...Forced cast from Object.Type to AnyClass always succeeds, did you mean to use 'as?'...)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2448

For now, you can probably specify

```
pod 'RealmSwift', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

In your Podfile to hide the warnings in your project.